# $\Bbb{R}^\omega$ with the Uniform Metric is not 2nd Countable

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, separable-spaces, second-countable

I'm trying to show that $\Bbb{R}^\omega$ with the uniform metric is not 2nd countable or separable (either one will work, since they are equivalent for metric spaces). My idea was to transfer the proof that $\Bbb{R}_\ell$ isn't second countable into the $\Bbb{R}^\omega$ setting. If $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for $\Bbb{R}_\ell$, then $x \mapsto B_x \subseteq [x,x+1)$ is an injection between $\Bbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{B}$, which shows that $\mathcal{B}$ is uncountable. How do I do something similar in $\Bbb{R}^\omega$? My first guess was that $x = (x_1,x_2,...) \in (0,1) \times \{0\} \times...$ being mapped to $B(x,x_1)$ might work, but quickly discovered the contrary. I could use a hint.

Answer (score 4):

Try diagonalisation: Suppose $D$ is a countable dense set in $\mathbb{R}^\omega$.
Say $D = \{d_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and each $d_n = (d_{n,1}, d_{n,2}, d_{n,3} \ldots)$. Then define $x_n = d_{n,n} + 1$ for all $n$ and this defines a point $x$ that has distance $1$ to each of the $d_n \in D$.
Conclude that $D$ could not have been dense after all.

Comment: I don't understand how we can say that the distance of point $x$ is $1$ to each $d_n$, with this construction, we only get $d_U((x_n),(d_1)) \ge 1$.

Comment: Just for clarity:  If $y=(y_n)$ and $z=(z_n)$ $\in \mathbb{R}^\omega$ then  $d_U(y,z) = d_U((y_n),(z_n)) = sup_n\{  \frac{1}{n}min\{ 1,|y_n-z_n| \} \}$.

Comment: @Sabhrant No, $d_U(y,z)= \sup_n  \min(1, |y_n -z_n|)$, see Munkres, e.g. So $1$ is the maximal distance between points.

Comment: @Sabhrant See around page 125 of Munkres. Your metric is the one that induces the product topology. Thm 20.5

Comment: thank you @Henno Brandsma

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for any subset $A \subset \omega$, consider the element $1_A$ which has 1s in the positions which are in $A$, and 0 in others.  (If you think of the elements of $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ as functions from $\omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$, this is an indicator function.)  There are uncountably many of these.  Now find a collection of disjoint open sets, each containing one of these elements.